# SQL Server transfer 6,000,000 records from one server to another server - fast

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

What is the fastest way to transfer 6,000,000 records between two servers in different locations, using SQL Server 2005?

Comment: I'm not allowed on the source server to get the backup file. The location is in another state. I have only read permission and permission to generate schemma scripts (only in the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use `bulkcopy` in `C# .Net` (example below). You can set the number of records to be transferred per transaction. Depending on network speed, will transfer in a few minutes. I had to transfer a table of IPs per city and I used the code below.

```
public class BulkCopy
{
    public string IPCIDADE()
    {
        string ret = "";

        using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
                          new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();



            // Get data from the source table as a SqlDataReader.
            SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT [IP_START], [IP_END], [PAIS], [ESTADO], [CIDADE] FROM [dbo].[IPCIDADE];", sourceConnection);
            SqlDataReader reader =
                commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

            // Open the destination connection. In the real world you would  
            // not use SqlBulkCopy to move data from one table to the other  
            // in the same database. This is for demonstration purposes only. 
            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =
                       new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx"))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                // Set up the bulk copy object.  
                // Note that the column positions in the source 
                // data reader match the column positions in  
                // the destination table so there is no need to 
                // map columns. 
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                        "[dbo].[IPCIDADE]";
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000; //Number of records by transaction
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

                    try
                    {
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy 
                        // object is automatically closed at the end 
                        // of the using block.
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```